# Remove old domain name from Active Directory

Tags: dns, active-directory, active-directory-group, domaincontroller, cognos-11

I have setup Active Directory on Windows Server 2019 with forest name as `abc.def.net` but we got to know that we need to change this domain name to `ab.de.net`.

Although I managed to make changes but now users are able to login using both the domains. I want users to only login using the second domain name - `ab.de.net`.

In fact if there is any way I can delete the old domain, please let me know.

Regards,
Pushp

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for programming questions. You might get better help at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: Follow the 24,25,26 steps number of this [Document](https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/step-by-step-how-to-rename-domain-name-in-windows-server-2016/)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your scenario in my environment and I am able disconnect and delete the old domain.

Earlier my DC was connected with `contoso.local domain`.You can see in below picture.

[image]

Now I have added a new zone `ab.de.net` using DNS Manage->ForwardLookupzone

changed DC domain to `ab.de.net`

[image]

Now My DC users is shown up for both the domain.

[image]

Now Open cmd and type `rendom /clean`. This is to remove references of the old domain name from AD.

Next, type `rendom /end`. This is to unfreeze the forest configuration and allow further changes.

Once I have run the above commands it has removed the reference of my old domain.

[image]

You can refer this [Document](https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/step-by-step-how-to-rename-domain-name-in-windows-server-2016/) for the detailed explanation.

**OR you can directly delete the Old Domain from here as well.**

[image]

Comment: Please vote to close this question (it belongs on ServerFault), rather than posting an answer. The question is off-topic here, and this question will likely go away (along with your answer, unless it's properly migrated)